# Is CAP theorem wrong?

Tags: sql, database, database-design, nosql

CAP theorem definition taken from Wikipedia:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAP_theorem

> It is impossible for a distributed computer system to simultaneously provide all three of the following guarantees:
>
> - Consistency (every read receives the most recent write or an error)
> - Availability (every request receives a response, without guarantee that it contains the most recent version of the information)
> - Partition tolerance (the system continues to operate despite arbitrary partitioning due to network failures)

My thought:

For any system with CA, they can operate normally without partition. When partition exists, the system can fall back to CP or AP, which can continue to operate. Since the system can continue to operate, it also fulfill P. Therefore, any CA system is also a CAP system. Thus the claim that it is impossible for all CAP to coexist in a system is wrong.

Comment: Not sure what's wrong with this question? Total valid, albeit false, theory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

C and A mean that the system provides these guarantees *in the face of partitions*. So abandoning these properties during a partition makes the property not hold.

The CA trade-off is only relevant during a partition (because without partitions we can give up P and obtain CA). Then, you need to decide.

The practically relevant choices are CP vs. AP since partitions can always happen.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you mean CAP is a state, since you said "without partitions we can give up P and obtain CA"?

Comment: CAP is a property of the system and for one property to hold it must hold at all times. A better phrasing would be "If we assume there are no partitions we should build a system that is CA because we don't need property P."

Comment: So CAP theorem is actually about picking 1 out of CA, rather than 2 out of CAP. If CAP is a propery that must hold true at all times, then in the presence of partitions, CA system could not keep its guarantees. Thank you for clearing up my confusion.

Comment: @netok It's still sorta two-out-of-three. Read https://www.infoq.com/articles/cap-twelve-years-later-how-the-rules-have-changed which is cited in the Wikipedia article. "Allowing at least one node to update state will cause the nodes to become inconsistent, thus forfeiting C. Likewise, if the choice is to preserve consistency, one side of the partition must act as if it is unavailable, thus forfeiting A. Only when nodes communicate is it possible to preserve both consistency and availability, thereby forfeiting P. The general belief is that for wide-area systems, designers cannot forfeit P..."

Comment: Or, another phrasing is "Assuming there are no partitions we obtain a stronger result which is all 3 of CAP."

Answer (score 1):

> Firstly, About Your Assumptions.

Actually `CA` and `CP` is identical, as what will happen if `CA` system get a network partition, it will lose `Availiability`. So sooner or later that will happen, as the chances that anyone of your nodes will fail jumps `exponentially` as the number of nodes increases.

You need to know that when you neglect an option in `CAP Theorem` as to Choose `CA` and neglect or leave `P`, that will hold for the whole lifecycle of your distributed system. And, thus we can not achieve `CA` practically, while effectively we can reach this as with Google Cloud Spanner Database which states that it is `99.999%` Avaliable, so it doesn't guarantee that there will be `100%` Availability, but it guarantee that it will be so small that it may be neglectable for Business.

Also, Postgresql Database can effectively achieve `CA` Through Replication.

All the Databases above try to maintain `CA`, by keeping a Degree of Consistency and Availability.

> Secondly, Is CAP theorem wrong?

There is some Critique points to `CAP Theorem`:

1. The only fault considered by the `CAP Theorem` is a network partition, that kind of fault absolutly happens, but it's not the only kind of thing that can go wrong as nodes can crash, you can hit a bug in the software, so we need to consider much wider range of trade-offs.
2. `CAP Theorem` says nothing about `latency`, which people tend to care about more than availability. In fact, `CAP Theorem` available systems are allowed to be arbitrarily slow to respond and can still be called Available. users wouldn't call our system `Available` if it takes 2 minutes to load a page.
3. Systems that tend to give up `Consistency` for `Availability` when there is a `partition`, also tend to give up `Consistency` for `latency` when there is `no` `Partition`.
4. `C` and `A` in `CAP Theorem` are `Asymmetric`, as systems that sacrifice `Consistency`(AP systems) tend to do so all the time, not just when there is a network partition. Also, the same for Systems that sacrifice `Availability`(CP systems) it tends to do so all the time, not just when there is a network partition. That means it is not `Consistent` all the time or not `Available` all the time. In the previous two cases they are unavialable useless systems, as `CAP Theorem` doesn't give us a view of what will happen when the system operates normely.